# I cant install nodejs in my pc. can anyone help me?

Tags: node.js

This is the error message - install Node.js Failed to open XML file C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_etw_provider.man,system error:-2147221164

Comment: Try repairing the installation? If you really can't you can download the zip version and manually add it to PATH. You're using Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your installer failed to open the

> node_etw_provider.man

file located in the

> C:\Program Files\nodejs

directory, with the error code -2147221164 which means "Class not registered".

This might be related to a privilege issue, Check if you have administrative privileges to install software on your system and try running the node.js installer as an administrator by right-clicking on the installer and selecting "Run as administrator". Sometimes security and antivirus software are also responsible for not letting the installer work, try disabling that for node.js installation purposes.